# Email sender tweaking help needed

Tags: email, google-sheets

I've been trying to understand this email on edit function. 
I just cannot figure it out.

I need to send informations in Columns A, B, C, F, G, H and J. The email trigger is in column K and would be selected from data validation. 
I have the following function which works great. It send the email but I cannot adjust which rows to show here. 
What am I doing wrong?

I want body of the Email to appear as follows when I choose email in K101

```
Headers in A3 : Data in cell A101
Headers in B3 : Data in cell B101
Headers in C3 : Data in cell C101
Headers in F3 : Data in cell F101
Headers in G3 : Data in cell G101
Headers in H3 : Data in cell H101
Headers in J3 : Data in cell J101
```

Help???

```
function mailOnEdit(e) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.getName() !== 'Registry Sheet' || e.range.columnStart !== 11 || e.range.rowStart < 4 || !e.value) return;
    var h = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 8)
        .getValues()[0],
        val = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 8)
            .getValues()[0],
        i = 0,
        body = "",
        notCols = [3, 4];
    while (i < 7) {
        if (notCols.indexOf(i) == -1) {
            body += h[i] + ": " + val[i] + "\n";
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    body += "\n\n Contact customer within 30 minutes and reply. Thanks";
    MailApp.sendEmail(e.value, "New job", body)
}
```

Comment: You might want to read documentation of [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your headers are in row three and not in row one. So
Change

```
var h = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 8).getValues()[0]
```

to

```
var h = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, 8).getValues()[0]
```